# SQL trying to find amount of years since

Tags: sql, database, oracle, to-date, to-char

I'm trying to find the years since a student enrolled.

Question:
Create a list of student names along with the number of years since they enrolled (round to 2 decimal places) for those students from area code 212.

My code:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, TO_DATE(enrollment_date) - TO_DATE(sysdate) Years
FROM student
WHERE phone LIKE '212%'
ORDER BY years;
```

I am having trouble finding the years. I have to use TO_DATE or TO_CHAR to find it out. Sysdate is what I'm trying to use to compare. I've hit a road block and don't remember how to do it.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using? Oracle? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    SELECT first_name, 
           last_name, 
           ROUND((MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, TO_DATE(enrollment_date)) / 12), 2) AS Years
    FROM student
    WHERE phone LIKE '212%'
    ORDER BY years;
```

Comment: It gave me an error.

Error at Command Line:3 Column:38
Error report
SQL Error: 0RA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Its still giving me an error. Error starting at line 1 in command:
SELECT first_name, 
       last_name, 
       ROUND((MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, DATE REGISTRATION_DATE) / 12), 2) Years
FROM student 
WHERE phone LIKE '212%' 

Error at Command Line:3 Column:39
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: When I edited my answer, I also changed `DATE enrollment_date` to `TO_DATE(enrollment_date)`. I hope this fixes the error as I can't see anything wrong otherwise.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that at first. Looks like its working now :) Thanks!